# estout: Controlling number of decimals using estpost summarize

Tags: stata

I'm using `estout` to create a table of summary statistics in LaTeX.

```
estpost summarize Var1-Var20
esttab using summarystatistics.tex, replace booktabs  cells("count mean sd min max") noobs nomtitles nonum
```

This produces more significant digits than necessary, though. I would like to have at most 4 digits for each variable.

I couldn't find the option for this in the help file nor any information online. I know I could control the digits after comma using `sutex`, but I'd prefer `estout` for the `booktabs` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maarten goes straight to the point. Below an example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

estpost summarize length weight
esttab using summarystatistics.tex, replace booktabs  ///
    cells("count mean(fmt(2)) sd(fmt(2)) min max") noobs nomtitles nonum
```

The `fmt()` suboption for `cells()` is documented in `help estout`.

Comment: Can I specify the format for all variables? For example,

`local stats count mean sd min max` 
`estpost summarize length weight` 
`esttab using summarystatistics.tex, replace booktabs  ///` 
`    cells("`stats' (fmt(%2.2f)") noobs nomtitles nonum`

Answer (score 3):

The `fmt()` option governs the number of digits.